# Changing a JLabel while GUI is running

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

The code as I have it now does work in changing the JLabel, but the issue is that after the first change, it only adds onto the label, rather than changing it like I intended. The code is as follows.

```
public static void changeJLabel(JPanel panelName, JLabel JLabel, String newText)
{
    panelName.remove(JLabel);
    JLabel = new JLabel(newText);
    panelName.add(JLabel);
    panelName.validate();
    panelName.repaint();
}
```

I set this to a button in the GUI, and the results are as shown in the following links. Before hitting button: http://prntscr.com/64gnwl Hitting it once: http://prntscr.com/64gnzj Changed as expected. Hitting it many times: http://prntscr.com/64go2u Not as expected. I presume it's not removing the JLabel before adding another, but I am not sure as to why. If you need my entire code, I will add that as well.

Comment: Why do you want to the label remove when you can simply change the text of the old one?

Comment: When I was changing the text, it didn't seem to actually change in the GUI. I might have been doing something wrong there as well. EDIT: I had not actually learned of .setText(). I'm amazed that this never came up in my multitude of searches.

Comment: try panelName.revalidate(); instead of panelName.validate(), But why you need to remove JLabel when you only need to change the text?

Comment: Kindly share the relevant code where you are updating the text. Is it a loop or on button click?

Comment: As stupid of a mistake as this is, I had not actually heard of .setText(). I changed it to that and it works fine.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the JavaDocs or [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JLabel.setText();` works for what I was wanting. I am learning as I go, and had not seen this method before in any of my searches. Not sure how I missed it, but this works fine.

```
public static void changeJLabel(JPanel panelName, JLabel JLabel, String newText)
{
    JLabel.setText(newText);
    panelName.validate();
    panelName.repaint();
}
```

Comment: This is not answer, you should either update your question or leave a comment

Comment: @MadProgrammer seems like a legit answer to me. OP answered their own question, which is completely acceptable.

Comment: @IngoBürk `panelName` is a `JPanel` and has no `setText` method

Comment: So there's a typo in the answer. That doesn't make it less of an answer.

Comment: Ah, I don't think I was clear. I'll update this answer with what I changed the class to.